# Проблема с компилятором

Tags: android, платежи, google-pay

сделал систему оплаты через google pay. И получаю такую ошибку:

```
C:\Users\ASUS G 731G\AndroidStudioProjects\JM\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\out\com\nikita\mozhaev\jm\databinding\ContentMainBinding.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
import android.widget.ConstraintLayout;
                     ^
  symbol:   class ConstraintLayout
  location: package android.widget
C:\Users\ASUS G 731G\AndroidStudioProjects\JM\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\out\com\nikita\mozhaev\jm\databinding\ContentMainBinding.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
  private final ConstraintLayout rootView;
                ^
  symbol:   class ConstraintLayout
  location: class ContentMainBinding
C:\Users\ASUS G 731G\AndroidStudioProjects\JM\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\out\com\nikita\mozhaev\jm\databinding\ContentMainBinding.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
  private ContentMainBinding(@NonNull ConstraintLayout rootView,
                                      ^
  symbol:   class ConstraintLayout
  location: class ContentMainBinding
C:\Users\ASUS G 731G\AndroidStudioProjects\JM\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\out\com\nikita\mozhaev\jm\databinding\ContentMainBinding.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
  public ConstraintLayout getRoot() {
         ^
  symbol:   class ConstraintLayout
  location: class ContentMainBinding
C:\Users\ASUS G 731G\AndroidStudioProjects\JM\app\build\generated\data_binding_base_class_source_out\debug\out\com\nikita\mozhaev\jm\databinding\ContentMainBinding.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
      return new ContentMainBinding((ConstraintLayout) rootView, imageChangeExplanation,
                                     ^
  symbol:   class ConstraintLayout
  location: class ContentMainBinding
```

Файл на который он ссылается:

```
// Generated by view binder compiler. Do not edit!
package com.nikita.mozhaev.jm.databinding;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.viewbinding.ViewBinding;
import com.nikita.mozhaev.jm.R;
import java.lang.NullPointerException;
import java.lang.Override;
import java.lang.String;

public final class ContentMainBinding implements ViewBinding {
  @NonNull
  private final ConstraintLayout rootView;

  @NonNull
  public final TextView imageChangeExplanation;

  @NonNull
  public final RelativeLayout interceptedNotificationLogoContainer;

  private ContentMainBinding(@NonNull ConstraintLayout rootView,
      @NonNull TextView imageChangeExplanation,
      @NonNull RelativeLayout interceptedNotificationLogoContainer) {
    this.rootView = rootView;
    this.imageChangeExplanation = imageChangeExplanation;
    this.interceptedNotificationLogoContainer = interceptedNotificationLogoContainer;
  }

  @Override
  @NonNull
  public ConstraintLayout getRoot() {
    return rootView;
  }

  @NonNull
  public static ContentMainBinding inflate(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater) {
    return inflate(inflater, null, false);
  }

  @NonNull
  public static ContentMainBinding inflate(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
      @Nullable ViewGroup parent, boolean attachToParent) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, parent, false);
    if (attachToParent) {
      parent.addView(root);
    }
    return bind(root);
  }

  @NonNull
  public static ContentMainBinding bind(@NonNull View rootView) {
    // The body of this method is generated in a way you would not otherwise write.
    // This is done to optimize the compiled bytecode for size and performance.
    int id;
    missingId: {
      id = R.id.image_change_explanation;
      TextView imageChangeExplanation = rootView.findViewById(id);
      if (imageChangeExplanation == null) {
        break missingId;
      }

      id = R.id.intercepted_notification_logo_container;
      RelativeLayout interceptedNotificationLogoContainer = rootView.findViewById(id);
      if (interceptedNotificationLogoContainer == null) {
        break missingId;
      }

      return new ContentMainBinding((ConstraintLayout) rootView, imageChangeExplanation,
          interceptedNotificationLogoContainer);
    }
    String missingId = rootView.getResources().getResourceName(id);
    throw new NullPointerException("Missing required view with ID: ".concat(missingId));
  }
}
```

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nikita.mozhaev.jm"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }



}

dependencies {
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:18.1.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".pays.Pay19">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Name"
        android:layout_width="389dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="107dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Введите ваше ФИО"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pay19"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="308dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="308dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="515dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        android:text="Оплатить"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Name"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Как это решить?

Comment: Вряд-ли в этом дело, но попробуйте убрать дублирующиеся зависимости. Также, вощзможно, вы не тот ConstraintLayout импортировали. Вроде бы он должен быть из androidx пакета

Comment: Возможно у вас в разметке не тот ConstraintLayout используется. Покажите ещё и файл разметки проблеммный

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Сейчас обновлю

Comment: @ЮрийСПб обновил

Comment: Вы пробовали удалить дублирующиеся зависимости?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Только, что сделал.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб сейчас обновлю

Comment: Это не помогло, как я понимаю?

Answer (score 0):

В импорте укажи правильную ссылку на класс.

```
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
```

Второй вариант включить DataBinding , указав его build.gradle

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это не сработает, он сам себя пересоздаёт при билде. Я пробывал

Comment: Попробуй добавить в gradle 

dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

Comment: Всё так же. Не помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было изменить build.gradle на это:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nikita.mozhaev.jm"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {

        dataBinding true

        // for view binding:
        // viewBinding true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:18.1.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```